# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error reading the C:\Windows\TEMP\ directory error occurring while debugging the ASP.NET project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

While debugging the project Visual studio showing some error.And when I am trying to add a table in database file(.mdf  extension) then the VisualStudio automatically restarts.
Error list-->

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error reading the C:\Windows\TEMP\ directory.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.IisExpress.SysTray.TrayAppHiddenForm.TrayAppHiddenForm_Load(Object sender,    EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Please Help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Hey It happen also with me , issue solved when I go to direct in directory C:\Windows\TEMP and system ask me access to this folder and I click yes for that so that current User has rights on that folder and error gone. This is access rights issue after my windows UPDATE

Answer (score -1):

This blog post definitely solved the problem that we were facing (This will describe the problem we were facing). - http://devatheart.azurewebsites.net/2011/04/18/troubleshooting-xmlserializer-failure/

We had this piece of code

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(RetrievedURL);
which was generating IE processes (Since IE was the default browser on the webserver) in the background on the button click and opening webpage.

Not a smart thing to have but we removed that code and it has definitely stopped the IE processes in the background.

How it is linked to XML Serialization Failure is explained in the above post. Thanks for the research and this blog post Slobodan Stipic, a.k.a. Slobo.

Hope this solution helps.